# Tag selection not saved

Tags: feature-request, new-nav

I think the tag filtering selection should be saved, but it is always revert to "recommended".
Repro :

- go to SO homepage, select  favorite tags from the menu
  [image]
- click on the logo to return the home page
- the menu reverts to recommended tags

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you added `favorite tags`.

you can check it by

> 1. Click- profile
> 2. Select - Edit profile & Settings
> 3. Select - preferences
> 4. Under - **Tags**

If `favorite tags` are empty it will redirect to some other pages

and this UI is now changed

Comment: of course I have some favorite tags.